# mac - can't install virtualbox with error "the installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail"

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, macos-monterey

when install virtualbox 6.0.24 on my macbook , macOS Monterey, Version 12.1 (21C52)

i got the error

```
The installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail
```

[image]

follow the [post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=95569), I got the log:

```
Jan  4 16:05:02 192-168-1-100 Installer[3349]: Could not load resource readme: (null)
Jan  4 16:05:02 192-168-1-100 Installer[3349]: Could not load resource license: (null)
Jan  4 16:05:14 192-168-1-100 installd[1220]: PackageKit: ----- Begin install -----
Jan  4 16:05:18 192-168-1-100 installd[1220]: PackageKit: PKInformSystemPolicyInstallOperation failed with error:An error occurred while registering installation with Gatekeeper.
Jan  4 16:05:21 192-168-1-100 installd[1220]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “VirtualBox.pkg”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=./postflight, NSURL=file:///Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VBoxKEXTs.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=org.virtualbox.pkg.vboxkexts, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “VirtualBox.pkg”.} {
            NSFilePath = "./postflight";
            NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cVirtualBox.pkg\U201d.";
            NSURL = "file:///Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VBoxKEXTs.pkg";
            PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "org.virtualbox.pkg.vboxkexts";
        }
Jan  4 16:05:22 192-168-1-100 Installer[3349]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
Jan  4 16:05:22 192-168-1-100 Installer[3349]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.
Jan  4 16:05:22 192-168-1-100 Installer[3349]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.'.
```

I also follow this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/360123) to add Oracle developer

```
spctl kext-consent disable
spctl kext-consent add VB5E2TV963
spctl kext-consent enable 
reboot
```

I also tried to disable gatekeeper

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

but no solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I successfully install it via brew

```
brew install --cask virtualbox
```

refer: https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/virtualbox

It is not a direct fix for the problem I met and discuss here, but just work. If you try other solutsions when search the errors and fixes in google, and still can't fix the problem, try this way.